# Unable to start editing from the last point of edit in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

Word 2013 has introduced a nice feature to display a balloon, when opening a document and to allow user to scroll down to the point of last edit in that document.

This balloon is displayed in my Word for exactly 0.5 seconds and I managed to click it once per about hundred of times so far. What am I missing. Is this a bug or a mentioned design feature? If second, then what reason is behind this?

Comment: Do you mean a default activated feature or is it the feature "track changes" on a document? Could you link the feature with a pricture of it?

Comment: @IvanViktorovic I mean a default feature, a small popup, that slides somewhere in the middle of the right margin and says, that you can click it to start your work from the point you ended it. This small popup slides back toward right margin for apparently 0.5 second, so I don't have much chances in clicking it and it took me five or so times to even understand, what it says. Adding a pictures doesn't have a much sense in this context, because the only copy of Word 2013 I have is in Polish, while this is English-based site.